# Use of namepsace and global classes

Tags: php, pdo, namespaces, spl-autoload-register

I suspect that the main issue I am experiencing here is my lack of understanding as to what is *really* happening with the `spl_autoload_register()` function.

Basically I am trying to start a new website and trying to use a better system than I have used before (Previous system was no classes, no structure, no anything really).

I am using a Linux box to write this on.

My structure is:

```
+index.php
-lib (folder)
    +toolset.inc.php
    -database (folder)
        +handler.php (uses PDO)
    -model
        +model1.php
        +model2.php
        +etc
```

and so on.

I am able to include any of these class files within the `lib` structure using the file `toolset.inc.php` which I call from `index.php`. However, I run into issues when I am trying to use PDO in `handler.php`.

toolset.inc.php:

```
<?php
namespace lib;

function load($classNameSpace) {
    echo $classNameSpace."<br />";
    $include_path = __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . str_replace("\\", "/", $classNameSpace) . ".php";
    if(is_readable($include_path)){
        require_once($include_path);
    }
}

spl_autoload_register(__NAMESPACE__ . '\load');

?>
```

index.php:

```
<?php
require_once("lib/toolset.inc.php");

use database\handler;

$test = new handler();
?>
```

/lib/database/handler.php (simplified version, in reality I read in connection details etc):

```
<?php
namespace database;

class handler{
    //define some connection stuff
    (...)
    function __constructor(){
         $attrs[PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE] = PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION;
         $this->connection = new PDO(...);
    }
}
```

While I can get the handler file to be included with the above `toolset.inc.php` file, I cannot get PDO to work inside it. I have been scouring forums, StackOverflow and tutorials for hours now and cannot find the information I am looking for.

Several posts and sites say that I need to declare PDO as an absolute by either using `use \PDO` or `$this->connection = new \PDO(...)` however in this case neither of these work.

I am at a loss as to why, and I am nearly completely convinced its because I have misunderstood something, or I am missing something very obvious. Can anyone explain ***why*** PDO can't be included this way, and what I would need to do to get it to include as required?

Many thanks

**EDIT :-** Error does vary depending which solution suggestion I try, but an example is:

```
Fatal error: Class 'PDO' not found in /var/www/html/toolset/lib/database/handler.php on line 63
```

While I know this says its looking for a file `PDO.php` in the `lib` folder, this is while calling it with `use \PDO;` or `$test =  = new \PDO(...)` which should apparently force it to use the PHP classes and not one in my specified directory (`lib`)

Comment: 1. this question has nothing to do with PDO or mysql. 2. "I cannot get PDO to work inside it." is not a question that is suitable for Stack Overflow. Did you get any error messages? If not - why? If yes - why do you keep them for yourself?

Comment: Knew I'd miss something having rushed it at work. Updated question.

The reason I had PDO in there is because I wasn't sure if it was the way I was trying to use PDO with the slashes (`$test = new \PDO(...)`) or if it was something to do with spl_autoloader and how I had it set up. Both could be causes. No idea where the sql tag came from.

Comment: Slashes belongs not to PDO but to namespaces. It doesn't matter, if it PDO, mysqli or datetime class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message seems pretty clear to me and it's not about namespaces. If PHP were looking for class `PDO` in your `database` namespace, the error message would read...

> Fatal error:  Class 'database\PDO' not found

It appears you simply haven't loaded the PDO extension.

FYI, once you *have* loaded the PDO extension, I suggest you use the `use` statement. Otherwise, you will have to prefix all uses of `PDO` with a backslash (including constants like `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE`)...

```
namespace database;

use \PDO;

class handler { ... }
```

Also, if all your file / directory names, class names and namespaces are lowercase, you can drop your autoloader and simply use the following...

```
// toolset.inc.php:

set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, [
    __DIR__, // "lib"
    get_include_path()
]));

spl_autoload_extensions('.php');
spl_autoload_register();
```

This will use the default implementation of [`spl_autoload`](http://php.net/manual/function.spl-autoload.php) which is written in C and much faster than any PHP implementation.

Comment: You are correct. It seems someone rebuild the server and hadn't restored the original config. Infuriating that its so simple!

Comment: @Rekarin I've added another point that may speed up your autoloading

Comment: Thanks, I've added it as my first `spl_autoload_register()` and my existing function as second to allow for the possibility of someone else writing it with capitals, or using 3rd party sources. Thanks again for your help and information!

Comment: By bad. Overlooked such a case.